# How can I detect if a row was inserted into the database x seconds ago

Tags: php, sql, time, spam

Basically, I'm working on a spam detection system and I would like to detect if a row was inserted less the x seconds ago. x could be 5 second, so I would want to see if a row was inserted into the table less then 5 seconds ago.

The table name for example purposes could be `my_table`. This is what I came up with...

```
$spam_validate = mysql_query("select * FROM my_table WHERE date_time < '3'");
```

Then I would do....

```
    if (mysql_num_rows($spam_validate)==0) {
    //keep going
    } else {
    echo 'Spam was detected';
    }
```

If any of you could point me into the right direction here, I'm obviously not correct so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Too bad there's not a MySQL equivalent to Oracle RowSCN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a timestamp field (can be of type [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)) in that table, which you set when you insert the row.

```
INSERT INTO foo (spam, eggs, timestamp) VALUES (42, 88, NOW())
```

Then you can select against it.  This query should work.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE timestamp BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) AND NOW()
```

Note the DATETIME arithmetic, which is similar to using [DATEADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) directly.

Comment: It is a `date_time` field type, but I do use the `now()` SQL function to use the date? So does that count or does the field type have to be a `timestamp`?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a timestamp into your database, then when you are taking in input from a user, grab the timestamp and check if their last post time plus X seconds (or throttle, perhaps would be a better word) is less than or equal to the current timestamp.

Here's a pseudo code example:

```
X = post_limit;
if((last_post_time + X) <= current_time)
{
    allow_to_post;
}
else
{
    do_not_allow_to_post;
}
```

Here's a snippet of code that I used in my imageboard software that might point you in the right direction as well:

```
<?php
$ip = $_REMOTE['SERVER_ADDR']; // client's IP address
$sql = "SELECT time FROM spam WHERE ip = '$ip' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if(0 < mysql_num_rows($query))
{
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if($result['time'] < $time)
        {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM spam WHERE ip = '$ip'";
            $return_val = mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO spam (ip,time) VALUES ('$ip','$time');";
    $return_val = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table should have a column (we'll call it `inserted_at`) of the type `timestamp`. You insert query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (inserted_at, somecol, someothercol) VALUES (NOW(), 'whatever', 76)
```

...and your check code would look like

```
$interval = 5;
$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS denied FROM tbl WHERE inserted_at > NOW() - $interval";
$spam_validate = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));

if ($spam_validate['denied']) {
  echo 'Spam was detected';
} else {
  // keep going
}
```