# Compare with mulitple dates and times in database

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, phpmyadmin

I'm making a system to make reservations for different items of equipment for the company I work for.

Now I have the whole system ready.  There is only one thing I can't get to work. I need a way to compare the given time  with all the times in the MySQL database for that specified date. The only problem I have that I can't get it to work if there are multiple records for one date. I already used a 'while' loop but than it also give multiple results.

So I need a way to check if the user-furnished time is free for reservation or not.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Share the code you have so far so we can take a look at what you're trying.

Comment: Where ReservationsStartTime(DBColumn) >= RequestedStateDateTime  and ReservationsEndTime(DBColumn) <= RequestedEndDateTime  will return all existing reservations which conflict with the requested reservation.  If no records are returned, then the reservation would be valid.

Answer (score 1):

We need some code to know for sure, but it really depends on how you're handling the slots. Do you have fixed windows for reservations (eg. four 15-minute windows per hour)? Or are they arbitrary (eg. One person could book 6:00 to 6:13 and someone else 6:13 to 7:00)?

If the problem is in your queries, remember that BETWEEN is your friend.  A snippet from [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650496/how-can-i-detect-if-a-row-was-inserted-into-the-database-x-seconds-ago/8650514#8650514):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE timestamp BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND) AND NOW()
```

So you could do something similar if you are checking that a time is booked:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE $time_to_check BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
```